# Shortcode in excerpt

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, shortcode, excerpt, post-type

I've a custom post type " Calendarize it ". And i would like to show at the end of the exerpt the custom taxonomy "Price". The price can be display by using this shortcode :

```
[rhc_term taxonomy="prix"]
```

I use this code :

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 'shortcodetext_in_excerpt' );
function shortcodetext_in_excerpt( $excerpt ) {
    $more = ' <a href="'. get_permalink( get_the_ID() ) . '">Lire la suite</a>';
    $content = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(), 35, $more );
    return preg_replace( '/\[[^\]]+\]/', '', $content );
}
```

And it works well. But how can i insert my shortcode. Who can help me.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Use this plugin: [Insert PHP Code Snippet](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/). It converts PHP snippets to shortcodes.

Comment: Where do you want to insert the shortcode? in the excerpt? You want to append the shorcode to the excerpt? Can you be please a bit more descriptive.

Comment: Yes.I use a custom post type. It allows me to create events that have attributes such as place, time of the event, and price. I use another plugin to display these events. This plugin takes the excerpt of wordpress. I would like to custom it to have: Excerpt - Event price- Read more.       Can i insert the shortcode in the excerpt ?